# Skipping the repeated part of a partially repeated hyphenated adjective

Tags: hyphenation

I read this in today's New York Times:

> The bloggers have become increasingly vocal in recent weeks in calling for an overhaul of Russia’s approach to war to protect its shrinking gains in Ukraine against an increasingly well-armed and -trained opponent.

Is it correct to skip "well" in the second use of the hyphenated adjective?  That is, should it be considered two words or one inseparable word?

Comment: In German this construction is legal and would count as better style than writing 'well-armed and well-trained'. But as your source is the NYT I somehow doubt that this came from a German native speaker trying to write in English.

Answer (score 2):

Is it correct? This is a matter of style, so it can’t be said to be incorrect unless someone’s the boss of you.

But no,  just no — don’t do that.

> **Amy Einsohn**: Suspended compounds of the form ‘water-based and -soluble paint’ are licit but likely to confuse readers; substitute ‘water-based and water-soluble paint.’
>  <sub>Source of cite:
> [ThoughtCo — Suspended Compound (Grammar)](https://www.thoughtco.com/suspended-compound-grammar-1692010)</sub>
>
>  <sub>Original source: [The Copyeditor’s Handbook by Amy
> Einsohn](https://www.ucpress.edu/book/9780520286726/the-copyeditors-handbook)</sub>